# binding flurl client to a specific network interface

Tags: flurl

with restsharp it's possible to bind requests to a specific network interface.

is it even possible with flurl so that I can tell my requests to use a specific local interface to use?

Answer (score 1):

Flurl is based on the `HttpClient` stack, which does not support this directly. If you're on the full .NET Framework (Windows), you can do it independently of `HttpClient`/Flurl via the `ServicePoint` for the URI you are calling:

```
var sp = ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(uri);
sp.BindIPEndPointDelegate = (servicePoint, remoteEndPoint, retryCount) =>
    new IPEndPoint(bindAddress, 0);
```

If you are on .NET Core, this is not supported at all (yet), but I get the impression that it will be eventually. You can follow [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/23426).

Comment: According https://github.com/tmenier/Flurl/issues/448 it became possible since NET5 and can be easily integrated into Flurl pipeline. A kind man made a sample code demonstrating the case https://github.com/bonesoul/dotnet_5_httpclient_rest_bind/blob/main/BindTester.cs